# Maven running Groovy integration tests using Spock testcontainers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, groovy, spock

I need to introduce integration tests into a Maven build for a Spring REST application. These test classes are written in Groovy and extends an abstract base class what is based on `spock.lang.Specification`.

The base class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@Testcontainers
abstract class Base extends Specification {
...
}
```

and a test class like this:

```
class SomeTestIT extends Base {

    @LocalManagementPort
    private int localManagementPort

    private RequestSpecification reqSpec

    def setup() {
        reqSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .setPort(localManagementPort)
            .build()
    }

...

}
```

The test are failing with the error `IllegalArgumentException: Port must be greater than 0`,
exception thrown by `io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl`. The annotated field is evaluated with zero. This annotation relies on the value of the `local.management.port` property.

I tried to set it as system property or as Spring Boot configuration property.

How can I achieve to have a non-zero port value for it?

Version for the used components:

Apache Maven 3.8.7
Java version: 17.0.6, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium
Groovy 3.0.13
gmavenplus-plugin: 2.1.0
springframework.boot:spring boot-test: 2.7.7
spockframework:spock-core: 2.3.groovy-4.0

Comment: Do you need a defined port? Why isn't a `RANDOM_PORT` enough?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan to set the port yourself via `server.port=<portnumber>`, then just use `RANDOM_PORT` instead of `DEFINED_PORT`.

So change the line

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
```

to

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```